# AngularJS set manually input to invalid inside for each loop

Tags: angularjs

I want to manually change the input to `$invalid` using AngularJS. And I found a [good example](http://plnkr.co/edit/HivNxb8CB7UfDseoOFbs?p=preview) of how to do it.

But in my case, I have a few forms inside loop and when I do the same I get the following error:

[See example](http://plnkr.co/edit/IUUNowQR5dIhk8OpSXlU?p=preview)

```
Cannot set property 'check' of undefined
```

Can't find out how to fix it.

Answer (score -1):

Your code

```
 <div ng-repeat="form in forms">
          <form name="myForm">
            <input name="ccNumber" ng-model="ccNumber" data-ng-change="check()">
            <span ng-show="myForm.ccNumber.$error.minLength">A cc number should be minimum 10 chars</span>
            <span ng-show="myForm.ccNumber.$error.maxLength">A cc number should be maximum 13 chars</span>

         </form>
         Form is valid is {{myForm.$valid}}
         <br/><br/>

         </div>
```

See your `<input name="ccNumber" ng-model="ccNumber" data-ng-change="check()">` have the input field `name` property is same, because every loop create a new input filed with the same `name` property. So angular can't identify the click event, which is clicked.

So you need set sequence `name` to your input filed, like my below code

```
  <div ng-repeat="form in forms">
          <form name="myForm">
            <input name="ccNumber{{$index}}" ng-model="ccNumber" data-ng-change="check()">
            <span ng-show="myForm.ccNumber{{$index}}.$error.minLength">A cc number should be minimum 10 chars</span>
            <span ng-show="myForm.ccNumber{{$index}}.$error.maxLength">A cc number should be maximum 13 chars</span>

         </form>
         Form is valid is {{myForm.$valid}}
         <br/><br/>

         </div>
```

Comment: seems like it doesn't help. please take a look http://plnkr.co/edit/IUUNowQR5dIhk8OpSXlU?p=preview